Anti-wolf-killing movie from the 1970s?
In the 1970s I remember seeing a movie about wolves that was critical of killing them. I thought it was called "El Lobo", but I could not find any movie by that name. It may have been a Disney movie made around 1975. I remember one really sad scene in the movie where the wolf is stuck in a trap waiting for the hunter to come kill him.
It was a live action movie and it takes place in a desert setting, like Mexico or the New Mexico.
What was this movie?

The movie is the "The Legend of Lobo" (1962).
The movie takes place in the Southwest. Lobo's father gets caught in a trap and shot by the cattlemen. Also, at the end Lobo's mate gets caught in a trap and killed. It is a Disney movie.
